# Katalon - recording on incognito mode

Tags: katalon-studio, incognito-mode, katalon-recorder

I went through the instructions [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/start-browsers-in-private-mode.html), but still when pressing on record web (on chrome of course) I still get the regular browser and not incognito mode. 
Maybe there is a way to change this in the testCase script?

How can I record using incognito?

Here are my settings:
[image: Here are my settings:]
I of course pressed apply :-)

Maybe I am running it wrong?
Here is how I run it:

[image: Here is how I run it:]

P.S.
I also tried to do so in Firefox and was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change you are doing in the settings are for the execution and not for the recorder/spy.

For recording using Katalon:

1. Install the Katalon extension on your browser
2. Allow Katalon extension (in chrome) to be loaded also for incognito mode.
3. open an incognito browser
4. in katalon studio execute recorder/spy
5. in recorder/spy choose active browser - this will connect your recorder to incognito window that was opened in step 3

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to capture in incognito mode?

Comment: 1. allow Katalon extension (in chrome) to be loaded also for incognito window<br>
2. open incognito browser<br>
3. in katalon studio execute recorder/spy<br>
4. in recorder/spy choose active browser - this will connect your recorder to incognito window that was opened in step 2.

Comment: Regarding downloading the extension on incognito: I get an error that it is not available on incognito mode. Also I am unable to find any option on my regular Katalon extension to make it work on incognito (I tried to search for this)

Comment: chrome: settings -> extensions -> Katalon recorder -> Details -> Allow in incognito

Comment: Thanks, for me it is: chrome: (right click) Katalon extension -> Manage extentions  -> Allow in incognito     Tomorrow will check if the whole process will solve this, thanks!

Comment: Yep Thanks! it works. I will later edit your  answer with your comments or you can edit it and will tag it as an answer